# how can I detect if an NSString ends with mp4 in iphone

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have a `NSString` and I want to detect if it ends with mp4 and then use a `VideoView` to open it.Is there a way to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *extension = [myString pathExtension];
BOOL isMP4 = (extension && NSOrderedSame == [extension caseInsensitiveCompare:@"mp4"]);
```

That will tell you if it ends with ".mp4" as its path extension. What's a `VideoView`?

Comment: Shouldn't even need the first part of that test, since you an always message nil (and get 0/NO back).

Comment: Ah, but `0 == NSOrderedSame`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way than Jonathan's method:

```
BOOL isMP4 = [[myString lowercaseString] hasSuffix:@".mp4"];
```

If you need to break up an `NSString` that represents a file path into its components, or append a directory/file name, then the `path` methods are indeed helpful. In this case though, I think it's cleaner (and much easier to read) to use the above.